# how to find max, min and average by using if technique in a 2d array in python

Tags: python

```
x=[[80,59,34,89],[31,11,47,64],[29,56,13,91],[55,61,48,0],[75,78,81,91]]
```

I want to find maximum minimum and average value of the above 2d array.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why use `if`? You can 1) Flatten the list of lists and then take max, min, avg OR 2) use the fact that it is a 2d list and use a double loop

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: ScootCork my expected outcome is max = 91, min = 0 and avg = 54.65

Comment: Putnam I've tried the following program so far:x=[[80,59,34,89],[31,11,47,64],[29,56,13,91],[55,61,48,0],[75,78,81,91]]
max= numbers[0]
for num in numbers[1]:
    if num > max:
        max=num
        numbers = range(x)
print(max(numbers))

Comment: [This answer on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/334823#334823) has some good guidelines on asking/answering homework questions. @XinfinityX consider editing in some context about your existing attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: @MLarionov i've tried it and also posted my solution but it is not correct thats why i posted here thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy` module to find min and max values easily:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[80, 59, 34, 89], [31, 11, 47, 64], [29, 56, 13, 91], [55, 61, 48, 0], [75, 78, 81, 91]])

minValue = np.min(x)
maxValue = np.max(x)

print(minValue)
print(maxValue)
```

If you need to find them without build-in methods, you can use an approach as follows:

```
x = [[80, 59, 34, 89], [31, 11, 47, 64], [29, 56, 13, 91], [55, 61, 48, 0], [75, 78, 81, 91]]

minValue = x[0][0]
maxValue = x[0][0]
sumAll = 0
count = 0

for inner in x:
    for each in inner:
        if each > maxValue: maxValue = each
        if each < minValue: minValue = each
        sumAll += each
        count += 1

average = sumAll / count
```

In this approach, you compare each value to find min and max. At the same time sum, count each element to calculate average.

Answer (score 0):

You can get maximum , minimum and average of 2D array with using map like

```
def Average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst) 

x=[[80,59,34,89],[31,11,47,64],[29,56,13,91],[55,61,48,0],[75,78,81,91]]

maximum = max(map(max, x)) // 91
minimum = min(map(min, x)) // 0 
average = Average(list(map(lambda idx: sum(idx)/float(len(idx)), x))) // 54.65
```

Comment: i can do  like this but i have to use if technique not the built-in functions of max and min

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to flatten the 2d array into an 1d array.

```
import numpy as np
x=[[80,59,34,89],[31,11,47,64],[29,56,13,91],[55,61,48,0],[75,78,81,91]]
x = np.array(x)
print(max(x.flatten()))
print(min(x.flatten()))
print(sum(x.flatten())/ len(x.flatten()))
```

Comment: i tried but it is giving an error : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: you should install the library using pip